# How to check if a number has certain digits without a particular order(for example 9-4-7-6). java

Tags: java

how to check if a number has certain digits without a particular order,
for example:

1. digits = 5-2-3-1
2. user input = 1235
3. return true

Comment: How the reference digits sre stored: a number, a string, an array, a collection?  Are duplicate digits allowed in the reference digits and the user input?  Could you show some code of your own attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the number as well as the input in accending or descending order and check if the number equals the user input. If it does return true otherwise return false.

Edit:

I am leaving it up to you how to sort it. I gave only an idea. It seems a homework assignment so try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

The counting sort algorithm is best suited for this task since we can only have 10 possible digits (0-9).

1. You can iterate through each character of the character string, storing it into a sorted counting array only if it is a valid single digit (0-9). For instance, reading the target string 5-2-3-1-7-8-5 should result in the counting array [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0]. For every position, we store the number of occurences of each digit from 0 through 9. Here, index 6 represents the number of instances of 5, which occured twice in our example target text.
2. You can do the same for the user input. For instance, the input 1235 should result in a counting array of [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0].
3. Then you can compare each corresponding value of the two arrays. You can check if targetCount[index] * inputCount[index] > 0. This condition will only become false when the digit is not present on either one or both arrays, since 0 * 0 = 0 and also, 0 * 1 = 0.
4. The function should return true only when all of the digits are contained in the target array, as verified by STEP #3. However, if not all digits of the user input occur in the target string, it's up to you what result you expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, as it was mentioned by Ryan, we have only 10 possible values (0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9). We assume that we have defined, what digits we want to look for.
To find if input number contains digits we look for, we have to traverse it at least once (which will give us complexity **O(N)**). I omit sorting intentionally, as it would cost us **O(n log n)** (unless we try *Bucket Sort*).
I recommend you to attempt solving a problem by yourself :)
However I leave a simple example solution to the problem:

```
public class CheckNumbers {
    public static boolean containsDigits(List<Character> digits, String number){
        // collection stores, if specific number has already occured. certainly, 
        //if numbers will be provided in string format e.g. "2-3-4-5", you need to split string first, 
        //like that: Arrays.stream("2-3-4-5".split("-")).collect...
        Map<Character, Boolean> numberOccurred = digits.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(n -> n, n -> false));

        for(char c: number.toCharArray()){
            numberOccurred.computeIfPresent(c, (num,val) -> true);
            
            // we can check if we have already found occurrence of all numbers we wanted to, 
            //because we don't want to count them, but just check them
            if(!numberOccurred.containsValue(false)) return true;
        }
        return !numberOccurred.containsValue(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CheckNumbers.containsDigits(List.of('1', '2', '5', '0'), "998706512234")); //true
        System.out.println(CheckNumbers.containsDigits(List.of('1', '2', '5', '0', '6', '3'), "99870651224")); //false
    }
}
```

This algorithm does not take into account e.g. if number provided starts with *0*